# firebase NuxtJs Check if the user is logged in

Tags: firebase, authentication, nuxt.js, middleware

How do I know if a user is logged in after a page reload (by cookies)

middleware :

[image]

The result, whether logged in or not, is:

[image]

but :

[image]

Comment: Are you using Nuxt Firebase or Firebase web SDK? Can you share the code so we can also see the imports and initialization?

Comment: use nuxt/firebase